# Game in android

Tags: android

I need to create a game in android for my final year project. I have created three games which are just a quiz game, punctuation game and jumble word game.

But I have been looking through many tutorials on the net and noticed it is not that difficult to create a more advanced 2D game. The game needs to support English in secondary education.

One of the tutorials I have been looking at is, along with playing with the LunarLander:

http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-v,188.html

If I was to make a platform game what is the best way just to get one character on the screen, that can walk forward and the screen moves along with it. Not sure how to implement this, I have looked around but most games and tutorials which I have looked at are objects moving around on one screen. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have look at this http://replicaisland.net/ this is an open source android 2d scroll game

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. Do you know if I will be able to get a zip copy of the project, or will I have to manually add the classes etc to a new project?

Comment: and it is written by a google/android dev so it should have at least good code quality...

Comment: Is there a download available for this project?

Comment: yes incase you didnt find that here is the link http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late, but for Game Development in Android who may view this question later or may be for those Beginners who are interested in Android Game Development, just go to first [Obviam](http://obviam.net) and then please read the book for detailed instruction to create even your own game framework... I know that ReplicaIsland is a good game and you can also find the explanation regarding that on the book... The book is from Apress and the name of the book is

```
Beginning Android Games
```

who is also the writer of

```
libgdx
```

game library... And because the emulator doesn't still give support for OpenGL ES 2.0 you can develop with some trick like having Google Nexus phone with jMonkeyEngine 3.0 as that supports OpenGL ES 2.0 with Android Harness. You can have a look at [Cocos 2D](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/)... And that's more regarding game development on Android...

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of libraries that you can use. Basically you need to use tiles and sprites which are supported in the android but libraries like AndEngine and Box2D really adds some volume and physics to the movements. I know that many game developers have been using Unity3D, and contrary of what the name suggest, they also support 2D games. anyway, platform games (2D Games) are quite complex to create, and you have to be sure that your game difficulty level is set currently.

Good luck.